# Is it safe to solder headphone's cable that connected a pc by 3.5mm jack

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station

While I fixing headphone, I wore headphone on my ear and plugged in headphone wire to my computer. Then I was soldering the broken cable of headphone. When solder tip touch the cable, it was listened noisy from headphone. When suddenly I realized that is wrong idea. After this action I removed headphone my computer immediately and other worked headphone plugged in. When I listened worked headphone (play music), it is listened noisy music. I removed the wire of worked headphones from my computer and plugged in my computer again. Then it was become normal. One question:   Are my computer mainboard, cpu, gpu damaged?

Comment: Unlikely. Soldering can cause two things, Short circuits between different conductors, and heat. Depending on the length of the wire, it's unlikely to heat up the connector. But yeah, bad idea.

Comment: This seems to be a repair question, and out of our league to help.VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These audio drivers have their own protection circuitry and you usually couldn't damage the main boards through the audio ports.

The noise could be due to the poor contact of you audio jack with the port of your computer or the cable itself where you soldered isn't done properly or the cable itself is damaged elsewhere.

EDIT:
General practice is to never work on anything while it's powered. Unless you really know what you're doing and have taken the necessary precaution steps.